# Replace cordova-plugin-media with cordova-plugin-media-with-compression

Tags: ionic-framework, record, sample-rate

I am new to **ionic** and I want to **record** a file in wav format using **cordova-plugin-media-with-compression**.
Unfortunately, in my project **cordova-plugin-media** is used which doesnt support '**startRecordWithCompression()**' method hence i have to change the plugin.
**startRecordWithCompression** will help me in  setting '**SampleRate**' of recored file.
Can anyone help me either on how to set sampleRate of recorded file or how to **replace** '**cordova-plugin-media**' **with 'cordova-plugin-media-with-compression.'**

Comment: have you tried removing the plugin with `ionic cordova plugin remove cordova-plugin-media` and installing the other plugin?

Comment: I did. It did not work